# Powershell script to pass parameters using psexec in commandline

Tags: powershell, parameters, workflow

Hi I am trying to run a powershell script remotely to create the webapplication pool for 2 servers: Below is the code in my Website_pararrel.ps1 which i run on 2nd server:

```
 workflow pbatch{

 param ([string]$iisAppName,[string]$directoryPath,[string]$iisAppPoolName, 
 [string]$un,[string]$pw,[string]$path,[string]$servers)

 foreach -parallel ( $server in $servers)
 {             
     (InlineScript{

     Import-Module WebAdministration

     Set-Location "IIS:\AppPools"

    if (Test-Path $Using:iisAppPoolName -pathType container)
     {
        Remove-Item $Using:iisAppPoolName -recurse   
     }

        New-Item $Using:iisAppPoolName -Force           
        Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WhereIsTest -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value v4.0
        Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WhereIsTest -Name processmodel.identityType -Value 3
        Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WhereIsTest -Name ProcessModel.userName -Value $Using:un1
        Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WhereIsTest -Name processmodel.password -Value $Using:pw1





        })


   }

}

pbatch -servers $servers -iisAppPoolName $iisAppPoolName -un $un -pw $pw
```

and i run using this command from 1st servers:

```
Psexec \\CPDEVWEB03.blfdev.lab /s cmd /c %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file D:\Website_Parallel.ps1 -servers "xyz" -iisAppPoolName "Test" -un "***\****" -pw "*******"
```

But i get this error:

```
 Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty
 string.
 At pbatch:14 char:14
 +
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingVa
 lidationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl
 lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
 + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

  New-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty
 string.
  t pbatch:14 char:14
 +
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingVal
 idationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl
lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
+ PSComputerName        : [localhost]

  Set-ItemProperty : Cannot process argument because the value of argument 
  "obj"
  is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
  At pbatch:14 char:14
  +
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], PSArgum
  entNullException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Se
  tItemPropertyCommand
+ PSComputerName        : [localhost]

 Set-ItemProperty : Cannot process argument because the value of argument 
 "obj"
  is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
  cmd exited on CPDEVWEB03.blfdev.lab with error code 0.
```

Somehow the values of the variables from my commandline script is not getting passed to my powershell script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your `psexec` command line; does _local_ invocation of the script work?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the parameter for /c into single quotes ( ' ) so that it is noticed as one parameter.

Does the following work?

```
Psexec \\CPDEVWEB03.blfdev.lab /s cmd /c '%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "D:\Website_Parallel.ps1 -servers xyz -iisAppPoolName Test -un ***\**** -pw *******"'
```

Comment: No.. it gives me this error:PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
cmd exited on xyz with error code 1.

Comment: My fault, I did not wrap everything right. You need to put everything after the -file in quotes as well. I've used double quotes ( " ) since I've wrapped everything after /c in single quotes ( ' ) and therefore had to remove all your other double quotes.

Comment: Sorry- i still get the same error: PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. cmd exited on xyz with error code 1

Comment: Enclosing the script path passed to `-file` _along with the arguments to pass to the script_ in double-quotes never works - they must be individual arguments. Also, `cmd /c` not only works fine with _individual_ arguments (e.g., `cmd /c echo "hi there"`), it is often preferable, because it simplifies quoting.